# Angular 5 Classes don't get applied with ngClass directive

Tags: angular, angular5, ng-class

All functions from HTML are called but classes don't get attached. All classes are defined in the .css file. This component is hosted within other one. Can anyone see what is wrong and why classes are not applied?

If I use jQuery to .addClass() or .removeClass() classes are added/removed. But I would like to use Angular facility and not to use direct DOM manipulation.

This is my component

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-popup',
  templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popup.component.css']
})

export class PopupComponent implements OnInit {  
  @Input() functionName: string;                
  @Input() fileName: string;                  
  @Input() columnName: string;                


  ngOnInit() {
    this.startPopup();
  }

  startPopup() {   
     this.setMyModalClasses(this.functionName);
     this.setFunctionInputClasses(this.functionName);
     this.setResultBodyClass(this.functionName);
  }

  setFunctionInputClasses(in: string) {     
     return { 'visually-hidden': true };    
  }

  setResultBodyClass(in: string) {    
     return { 'text-active' : false, 'image-active' : true };      
  }

  setMyModalClasses(in: string) {    
      return { 'my-modal-initial': true, 'max-height-90': true };    
  }
```

}

and this is my HTML

```
<div class="my-modal" [ngClass]="setMyModalClasses()">
  <div class="my-modal-content">
    <div class="initial-display">
      <div id="functon-input" class="functon-input" 
                              [ngClass]="setFunctionInputClasses()">
        should not be on display
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="result-display">
      <div id="result-body" class="result-body" 
                            [ngClass]="setResultBodyClass()">
        ABC ABC ABC
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a typo in : sring for setfunctionInputClasses . Anyway why do that class functions have a parameter? It is not used in the html

Comment: which `.css` file are you declaring those css styles?

Comment: @KrishnanunniJeevan Thanks for noting type. I'll correct it. But this type not in my real code, only here. At to a parameter to the function... I simplified code to stay focused on the point (and, of course, I checked my simplified code before posting).

Comment: @Pengyy All css classes are in the popup.component.css file as per the  Component definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions returning styles, not classnames, so maybe instead of [ngClass] you should try [ngStyle].

Comment: No, my functions return css classes which, of course, have a bunch of styles.

Comment: the problem is that div not getting expected classes from setFunctionInputClasses or class="functon-input" ?

<div id="functon-input" class="functon-input" [ngClass]="setFunctionInputClasses()">

Comment: My setFunctionInputClasses() is trying to add additional classes to the div. In this particular case it needs to attach a visually-hidden class which is defined in css file like this:   
.visually-hidden { display: none; }

Comment: Where is .visually-hidden defined ? At popup.component.css or parent component css?

Comment: All the css classes (including visually-hidden) are defined in the  popup.component.css file.

Comment: Im out of ideas, but code containt some strange logic for my taste.

1) Why calling this.startPopup() in ngOnInit() , anyway functions do not make any side effects.
2) (in: string) - 'in' is reserved word in typescript, try to use something else.

Answer (score 0):

The function setMyModalClasses() is not passing in a parameter but in TS file it is expecting one. Same for all functions. 
I think startPopup() is unnecessary

Comment: What do you mean by saying: "... is not passing in a parameter..."? Could you provide your example for any of my functions?